# Generalized perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Given any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, does there exist solutions to  $\sigma(n)=kn$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$?

Perfect numbers correspond to $k=2$. Is there some sort characterization of these numbers?

$\text{For instance, similar to the following statement:}$

$\text{$n$ is an even perfect number iff $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$, where $2^p-1$ is a prime.}$

$\text{For $k=3$, for $n \leq 100,000$, $n=120$ and $n=672$ satisfy.}$

$\text{For $k=4$, for $n \leq 100,000$, $n=30240$ and $n=32760$ satisfy.}$

Interestingly for both these case, we have $k \mid n$
(similar to the conjecture that all perfect numbers are even).

$\text{The }$[asymptotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)$\text{ for the sum of divisors function does not rule out $k$ has to be finite.}$

Comment: +1 If I remember right, it is conjectured that the answer is yes. Interesting is, that it is not known, if there are perfect odd numbers.

Comment: They are called [multiply perfect numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_perfect_number).

Comment: That's a lot of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @bof Thanks. This is a good piece of information.

Comment: See OEIS [A005820](http://oeis.org/A005820), [A027687](http://oeis.org/A027687), [A166069](http://oeis.org/A166069) and links from those

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, existence of $k$-perfect numbers is open except for specific small $k$.

Your second conjecture, though, is false: $n=459818240$ satisfies $\sigma(n)=3n$ but $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked this number now. Good.

Comment: @Henry they are multiples of $4$ (Both end in $68$).

Comment: @Leslie: you are correct and I clearly need some sleep.